# How to Return a Comma Separated Value List to single Excel Cell based on Condition from Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table I need to look through and return the first row where every corresponding value in the second row is "Yes"

In my case this would mean:  "TA", and "RA"

```
+-----+----+-----+
| TA  | SA | RA  |
+-----+----+-----+
| Yes | No | Yes |
+-----+----+-----+
```

**Is there a way to combine these values into a single Excel cell separated by commas?**

So that a single cell will contain "TA, RA"

What formula I've used is store all values into an array and then have that array write to adjacent cells all values with yes and then combine them with substitute function.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$1,1,IFERROR(SMALL(IF($A1:$A3="Yes",COLUMN($A1:$A3)),ROW(1:1)), "")), "")

=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1&" "&B1&" "&C1&" "&D1&" "&D1)," ",", ")
```

**This will turn:**

```
+----+----+
| TA | RA |
+----+----+
```

**into:**

```
+--------+
| TA, RA |
+--------+
```

Is there a quicker/cleaner way to build this function to return all the values that match to "Yes" into a single cell separated by commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you against a custom function?

```
Function LISTTHEYESES(valuerange As Range)

Dim cell As Range, resultstring As String

For Each cell In valuerange
    If cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Yes" Then
        If resultstring <> "" Then
            resultstring = resultstring & ", " & cell.Value
        Else
            resultstring = cell.Value
        End If
    End If
Next cell

LISTTHEYESES = resultstring

End Function
```

[image: img1]

Comment: row1 = roles.Row
row2 = valuerange.Row
diff = row1 - row2;                     I added this to change the offset to reuse the function down the rows of data and subbed in for offset

Answer (score 3):

If you have Excel 2016+, you can use the `TEXTJOIN` function in an array formula.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(2:2="Yes",$1:$1,""))
```

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

[image]

Comment: It appears I need a subscription to Office 365 to use this function even though it appears to provide a simple solution

Comment: @WilliamHumphries Yes. The initial stand-alone version of Excel 2016 did not have this function.  I assume Excel 2019 has it, but don't know for sure.